# Split array data from fetch data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, axios

I fetch this data from the api

```
array : { "Blue": 8646, "Red": 3451, "Green": 2342}
```

then i want to split this into two array

```
arrayColor : ["Blue", "Red", "Green"]

arrayNumber : [8646, 3451, 2342]
```

i try using split function but it didn't work, when i check for array.length, console said it undefined.

when i `console.log(array)`

it show like this

```
Proxy { "Blue": 8646, "Red": 3451, "Green": 2342}
```

Help me please.

Comment: `const { array } = ajaxData; const result = { arrayColor: Object.keys(array), arrayNumber: Object.values(array) };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, This is not an array it's an object.

You can use Object.keys and Object.value to get data

```js
const obj = { Blue: 8646, Red: 3451, Green: 2342 };

const color = Object.keys(obj);
const value = Object.values(obj);

console.log("color :", color);
console.log("value :", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object contains a key and a value pair.
The color is the key and the number is the value. {"key":"value"}

To solve your issue you can do something like this:

```
let array = {"Blue": 8646, "Red": 3451, "Green": 2342};
let colors = [];
let numbers = [];
for(let key in array) {
    console.log(key);
    colors.push(key);
    numbers.push(array[key]);
}
console.log(colors);
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for split function and length not working is because the given data is an object and not a array.split function works only for arrays.The above answers seem to be the correct code.